# Openconnect VPN connecting, but work sites giving DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, systemd, openconnect

**EDIT: I have no idea why, but if I connect to NordVPN, then disconnect, my work VPN through `openconnect` works as it should. I can access all work and non-work sites as intended. Maybe this will shed some light?**

As the title states, I'm using `openconnect` on Ubuntu 20.04 to connect to my work VPN network. I've been running the command `sudo openconnect <work_vpn_gateway> -u <username>` and supplying my password generated from my RSA token for months now, and it's been just fine.
**Recently, however, I've been having issues.** I'm still able to connect just fine using that above command, but trying to connect to any of the sites that would normally work by being on the VPN now give me the error: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

I'm going to list as much info as I can, and hopefully someone will point out something which I missed.

If there's anything else that I could add which could be helpful, please let me know. I need this to function so I can do my work during the day, and I just don't understand what caused it to suddenly stop working. I did switch from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS about a week ago, but it was working for several days after that.

- This is the actual output of my VPN connect call:

  - ```
    $ sudo openconnect <work_vpn_gateway> -u <username>

    POST <work_vpn_gateway>
    Connected to 147.21.175.42:443
    SSL negotiation with <work_vpn_gateway>
    Server certificate verify failed: signer not found

    Certificate from VPN server "<work_vpn_gateway>" failed verification.
    Reason: signer not found
    To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
        --servercert pin-sha256:Q8...noq0qrszE=
    Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view: yes
    Connected to HTTPS on <work_vpn_gateway>
    XML POST enabled
    Password:
    POST https://<work_vpn_gateway>/
    Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
    Connected as 10.7.91.214, using SSL, with DTLS in progress
    Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS0.9)-(RSA)-(AES-256-CBC)-(SHA1).
    Error: any valid prefix is expected rather than "dev".        # I never saw this on 18.04
    **** # ^ This is the end-state of the connect call - I should be able to now access work sites ****
    ^CSend BYE packet: Aborted by caller                          # Manual exit here
    Error: argument "via" is wrong: use nexthop syntax to specify multiple via

    RTNETLINK answers: No such process
    User cancelled (SIGINT/SIGTERM); exiting.
    ```
- My `ifconfig` off VPN is:

  - ````
    docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
       inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
       ether 02:42:4b:9f:73:5c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
       RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    enp59s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
       inet 192.168.1.35  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279::1192  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279:cd37:ecd6:778a:d82c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279:6145:5e5f:87ec:82e2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279:5a6:71cd:fffb:ff1e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279:d4f5:9c29:dc90:1ad7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279:9028:f45d:3ce:ea0c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
       inet6 fe80::a487:d33c:c51:409  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279:89d5:b1fd:857c:384e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
       ether 30:9c:23:8e:fd:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
       RX packets 18734  bytes 10635469 (10.6 MB)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 15361  bytes 2864576 (2.8 MB)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
       device interrupt 17  

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
       inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
       inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
       loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
       RX packets 213  bytes 17919 (17.9 KB)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 213  bytes 17919 (17.9 KB)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
       inet 192.168.1.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
       inet6 fe80::75ad:b71b:40c:9240  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279:c527:a9fb:322e:51cf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279::19a5  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
       inet6 2605:e000:150a:d279:502d:e2e9:87ef:e856  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
       ether d4:6d:6d:3e:1f:7a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
       RX packets 2963  bytes 970984 (970.9 KB)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 847  bytes 139316 (139.3 KB)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0```
    ````
- When I connect to VPN, this is added to my `ifconfig` output

  - ```
    tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1406
       inet 10.7.91.182  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.7.91.182
       inet6 fe80::95d8:44b6:3061:37fe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
       unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
       RX packets 14  bytes 1882 (1.8 KB)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 29  bytes 2472 (2.4 KB)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    ```
- My `/etc/resolv.conf` off VPN:

  - ```
    # This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
    #
    # This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
    # all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
    #
    # Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
    # symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
    # replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
    #
    # See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
    # operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

    nameserver 192.168.1.1
    search lan
    ```
- My `/etc/resolv.conf` when connected:

  - ```
    # This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
    #
    # This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
    # all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
    #
    # Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
    # symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
    # replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
    #
    # See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
    # operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

    nameserver 192.168.1.1
    nameserver 147.22.178.40
    nameserver 147.22.179.9
    search lan directv.com
    ```
- Result of `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`:

  - `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jun 22 11:41 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`
- Ouput of `systemd-resolve --status` off VPN:

  - ```
    Global
            LLMNR setting: no                  
    MulticastDNS setting: no                  
       DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
           DNSSEC setting: no                  
         DNSSEC supported: no                  
    Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1         
            DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1         
            DNS Domain: lan                 
         DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                     16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     168.192.in-addr.arpa
                     17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                     corp                
                     d.f.ip6.arpa        
                     home                
                     internal            
                     intranet            
                     lan                 
                     local               
                     private             
                     test                

                         Link 4 (docker0)
                     Current Scopes: none
               DefaultRoute setting: no  
                      LLMNR setting: yes 
               MulticastDNS setting: no  
                 DNSOverTLS setting: no  
                     DNSSEC setting: no  
                   DNSSEC supported: no  

                            Link 3 (wlo1)
              Current Scopes: DNS        
        DefaultRoute setting: yes        
               LLMNR setting: yes        
        MulticastDNS setting: no         
          DNSOverTLS setting: no         
              DNSSEC setting: no         
            DNSSEC supported: no         
          Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
                 DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
                  DNS Domain: ~.         
                              lan        

                         Link 2 (enp59s0)
              Current Scopes: DNS        
        DefaultRoute setting: yes        
               LLMNR setting: yes        
        MulticastDNS setting: no         
          DNSOverTLS setting: no         
              DNSSEC setting: no         
            DNSSEC supported: no         
          Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
                 DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
                  DNS Domain: ~.         
                                      lan
    ```
- When I connect to VPN, only thing that changes is the following is added to output of `systemd-resolve --status`:

  - ```
    Link 12 (tun0)
       Current Scopes: DNS           
    DefaultRoute setting: yes           
            LLMNR setting: yes           
    MulticastDNS setting: no            
       DNSOverTLS setting: no            
           DNSSEC setting: no            
         DNSSEC supported: no            
    Current DNS Server: 147.22.116.240
            DNS Servers: 147.22.116.240
                         147.22.117.9  
             DNS Domain: directv.com
    ```
- My `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

  - ```
    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

    [ifupdown]
    managed=true

    [device]
    wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
    ```
- On a fresh restart of `systemd-resolved` (`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`) and looking at its status, nothing seems out of sorts. But when I connect to VPN (or try to access any of the work sites, even off VPN) the following shows up a bunch of times in `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved`:

  - `systemd-resolved[16885]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.`

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

After the vpn is up, did you try to comment the first line of `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

```
#nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 147.22.178.40
nameserver 147.22.179.9
search lan directv.com
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that - nothing changed.